# Best practices with deep routes in ember with ember-data

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript, ember-data

I have a router which looks like that:

```
App.Router.map ->
  @resource 'categories', ->
    @resource 'category', path: ':category_id', ->
      @resource 'composites', ->
        @resource 'composite', path: 'composite_id, ->
          @resource 'questions', ->
            #...
```

All plural routes have a model hook loading all the models depending on the parent (except the root resource loading all categories). Like composites model hook will do something like `App.Composite.find category_id: @modelFor('category').get('id')`.

So this is working but the thing I can't make work fully perfectly after trying many ways is the auto redirecting.
I want that once the categories have been loaded, to redirect to the category route using the firstObject loaded by categories route, and then redirecting to the composites route, and then redirecting to the composite route with firstObjevt loaded in composites route, etc.. until the end level.

I made it partially working using redirect, firstObjectObserver, ... but I often encounter a problem with infinite redirect, or not having the models loaded before trying to redirect to the next route with first model, ...

What is the best practice to do so? Should I rewrote my router in another way (I want to e able to have an URL for each level tho even if at te end it'll redirect automatically to the last level, tho the models can change)? How should I wait for the plural route models to load before redirecting?

Answer (score 3):

> What is the best practice to do so? Should I rewrote my router in another way

I would recommend flattening these resources - don't let the url structure dictate the route nesting, instead nest resources based on your templates and use the path property to specify the route/resource url. So unless your UI really has a very deeply nested master-detail template with categories, composites and questions, something like this would make more sense:

```
App.Router.map ->
  @resource 'categories'
  @resource 'category', path: '/categories/:category_id', ->
    @resource 'composites'
    @resource 'composite', path: 'composites/:composite_id, ->
      @resource 'questions'
        #...
```

> How should I wait for the plural route models to load before redirecting?

Either way, redirecting *should* work something like this:

```
App.CategoriesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Category.find({});
  }
});
App.CategoriesIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function() {
    var category = this.modelFor('categories').get('firstObject');
    this.transitionTo('category', category);
  }
});
```

Is that approach not working? Perhaps this will do the trick:

```
App.CategoriesIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function() {
    return App.Category.find({}).then(function(results) {
      var category = results.get('firstObject');
      return this.transitionTo('category', category);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorry hit enter instead of SHIFT+ENTER

For the first part of the answer, the thing is that a navbar of categories is shown and then uner it another navbar of composites for that category, and then a list of questions of that composite or details relate to one question, so I guess for mainly all I need to nest it more to have all models accessible like that:

`categories` => selected `category` => `composites` of this category => selected `composite` => `questions` in that composite, selected `question`

Comment: For the second part of the answer, I tried your approach but most of the time the `this.modelFor('categories')`wasn't loaded yet or finished to load, so I couldn't get the first object. It worked when I was using the `activate` hook of the `XxxxIndexRotue` until the last version of ember (RC6.1) where I posted a bug thought it was one and they answered it wasn't the way to do it. So here is the reason of my question here ;-)

Comment: Oh also `Route` suffix has to be part of the route class name of course (`CategoriesIndexRoute`) and `this.transitionToRoute` is `this.transitionTo`, `transitionToRoute` has to be used in controllers :-)

Comment: OK fixed those typos, also changed model hook to use `App.Category.find({})` instead of `App.Category.find()`. I always forget that `find()` with no query will not wait for server response before resolving the promise.

Comment: Well, find even with no query will wait for server response BUT it'll be marked as resolved while it's still in updating stage, and that's the problem I had to resolve using the solution in my own answer.

Comment: No it doesn't work, I have already tried this and the thing it that in the `then()` we still don't have the models loaded. So you need to return a promise which is gonna resolve to the first object when this one will be available, and in the resolve you have to do the redirect, as I did in my answer.

Comment: Makes sense. Seems odd that `App.Category.find({})` resolves before the models load, this could be an ember-data bug. I'll look into it but anyway glad to hear you've got a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I think I got it. I had to return a promise in the redirect to do the trick for plural routes:

```
App.CategoriesIndexRoute = Em.Route.extend
  redirect: (model, transition) ->
    models = @modelFor('categories')
    if (model = models.get 'firstObject')
      @transitionTo 'category', model
    else
      promise = Em.Deferred.create()
      observer = =>
        return unless (model = models.get 'firstObject')
        models.removeObserver 'firstObject', observer
        promise.resolve(@transitionTo 'category', model)
      models.addObserver 'firstObject', observer
      promise
```

And that would do the trick. I'm pretty sure there is a better solution, I've put that in a mixin for now but please, if you have any better solution thank you in advance to letting me know.